# Steps for computing Tor$(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, derived-functors, torsion-groups

I'm reviewing algebraic topology, in particular the Kunneth Formula. I can't find online or in my book (by Hatcher) an explanation for how to calculate $\mbox{Tor}(G,H)$ for any two groups. My understanding is that Tor measures the failure of a ses to be exact. **Could you please tell me the steps for calculating Tor in general?**

I'm piecing together tidbits from my notes and other questions on Stack Exchange. Here's what I could come up with for Tor$(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})$.

First take a free resolution of the first group, $\mathbb{Z}$ such as $0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$, since the integers form a free group without relations. Then tensor each group over integers and ditch the group on the left (since tensoring is right exact) to get $? \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$. Now find what $?$ must be in order for the sequence to be exact. In this case, $?=0$ so Tor$(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})=0$.

Comment: As $\Bbb Z$ is torsion-free, then $\textrm{Tor}(\Bbb Z,A)=0$ for any Abelian group $A$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider a commutative ring $R$ and some $R$-modules $M$ and $N.$ One can compute the $R$-modules $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M, N)$ in essentially two ways.

**1.)** Begin with a projective resolution of $N,$ e.g., $P_\bullet : \cdots \to P_2 \to P_1 \to P_0 \to N \to 0;$ then, apply the functor $M \otimes_R -$ to this to obtain a chain complex $$T_\bullet : \cdots \to M \otimes_R P_2 \to M \otimes_R P_1 \to M \otimes_R P_0 \to 0.$$ We define $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M, N)$ as the homology of this chain complex, i.e., $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M, N) = H_i(T_\bullet).$

**2.)** Begin with a short exact sequence of $R$-modules $0 \to K \to N \to I \to 0.$ By applying the right-exact functor $M \otimes_R -$ to this exact sequence, we obtain a long exact sequence of Tor, i.e., $$\begin{align*} \cdots \to \operatorname{Tor}_1^R(M, K) \to \operatorname{Tor}_1^R(M, N) &\to \operatorname{Tor}_1^R(M, I) \\ \\ &\to \operatorname{Tor}_0^R(M, K) \to \operatorname{Tor}_0^R(M, N) \to \operatorname{Tor}_0^R(M, I) \to 0. \end{align*}$$ One can prove that $\operatorname{Tor}_0^R(M, -) = M \otimes_R -,$ so this long exact sequence measures the failure of $M \otimes_R -$ to be left-exact. Under some mild assumptions, in this setting, one could say something about the vanishing of the higher Tor, or one could explicitly compute $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M, N).$

Here are just a few facts about $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M, N)$ that could come in handy for computations.

- We have that $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M, N) \cong \operatorname{Tor}_i^R(N, M),$ so always compute the easier of the two.
- If $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated, then $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M, N)$ is finitely generated
- Given that $M$ is a flat $R$-module, we have that $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M, N) = 0$ for all integers $i \geq 1.$ Conversely, if $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(M, N) = 0$ for all $R$-modules $N,$ then $M$ is flat as an $R$-module.
- Given a commutative ring $R$ with ideals $I$ and $J,$ we have that $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(R/I, R/J) \cong (I \cap J) / IJ.$
- Given an $R$-regular sequence $I = (x_1, \dots, x_n),$ we have that $\operatorname{Tor}_n^R(R/I, M) \cong (0 :_M I).$
- Tor commutes with direct sums, direct limits, and localization.

Comment: This is a very nice list; it might be a little more of an advanced tool, but I thought I'd just note that one can also compute $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M,N)$ by taking a projective resolution $P_{\bullet}$ of $M$ and a projective resolution $Q_{\bullet}$ of $N$ and taking the $i$th homology of $P_{\bullet} \otimes_R Q_{\bullet}$. Several of the standard proofs of the balancedness of $\operatorname{Tor}$ work through this fact.

Comment: That is a nice fact! I had not seen this before. I will think about that some more before adding it to the post. Thank you very much.